# Pass params to firestore collections

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-firebase

I want to know if its possible to pass `params` like `busstop` to `this.ref = firebase.firestore().collection(params)` to access different collection when navigation from one page to another. If not, how do i go about achieving this?

page1 - the user will have options of what to press to retrive data from firebase firestore.

Page1.js

```
onPress () = > this.props.navigation.navigate('page2',{locations: 'busstops' })


onPress () = > this.props.navigation.navigate('page2',{locations: 'taxis' })
```

page2

```
import {View,Text} from 'react-native';

const collectionid = this.props.navigation.state.params.location
const location = collectionid ? params.location : null;


export default class HomeDetail extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.ref = firebase.firestore().collection(location);

        this.state = {

            },

        };
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this is a `react-navigation` question and not a firestore one. Please check this link:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#getparam-get-a-specific-param-value-with-a-fallback

From the docs:

> In the past, you may have encountered the frightful scenario of
>   accessing a param when params is undefined. Instead of accessing the
>   param directly, you can call getParam instead.

They changed it from:

`const { location } = this.props.navigation.state.params.location;`

to

`const location = this.props.navigation.getParam(paramName, defaultValue);`

So try using this in your code:

`const collectionid = this.props.navigation.getParam('location');`